# Can a MapReduce be implemented using Java RMI?

Tags: java, mapreduce, rmi

I was planning to implement a MapReduce using Java RMI. For reference, I looked up on the web for any MapReduce implementation using Java RMI and I didn't find anything. So, this made me skeptical about its possibility. Could anyone tell me if it is possible? If not, why? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can, but it's a great deal of work.

You'll have to write *everything*: the file system, the job scheduler and manager, the mapper dispatcher, etc.

The real question is: Why would you want to?  What is the benefit of RMI that justifies this?

Answer (score 0):

I would start with one of the many open source libraries which does MapReduce already.  They could use RMI but might not mention it because they might not consider it important to MapReduce.

You can use Java RMI, or a wide number transports, to implement Map Reduce.

There is a lot more to MapReduce than having a transport. but RMI is fine.